# Moving files conditionally using shutil

Tags: python, python-3.x, linux, shutil

I am trying to move the files from a source directory to destination Dir in linux which are ending with `.text` extension with the timestamp using `shutil` but somewhat not working correctly, looks like i'm doing something wrong.

Below is the source Directory where files are:

```
$ ls -l /samba/smb_out/
-rw-r-----. 1 user1 tam 266852 Dec 16 21:41 fostert.20201215.text
-rw-r-----. 1 user1 tam 266852 Dec 16 21:41 fostert.20201216.text
```

### test code:

```
>>> tm_src = time.strftime("%Y%m%d")
>>> tm_dst = time.strftime("%Y%m%d-%H:%M:%S")
>>> src = "/samba/smb_out/"
>>> dst = "/samba/script_logs/"
>>> outfile = ( src + tm_src + ".text")
>>> text_files = [el for el in os.listdir(src) if el.endswith(".text") and path.isfile(path.join(src, el))]
>>> for file in text_files:
    shutil.move(path.join(src, file ), dst + "-" + tm_dst + ".log")
    
'/samba/script_logs/-20201216-21:32:59.log'
'/samba/script_logs/-20201216-21:32:59.log'
```

### desired Should be:

```
'/samba/script_logs/fostert.20201215.text-20201215-21:32:59.log'
'/samba/script_logs/fostert.20201215.text-20201216-21:32:59.log'
```

any idea what i'm doing wrong here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below should work for you, you just missed the `file` from your for loop.

```
>>> for file in text_files:
      shutil.move(path.join(src, file ), dst + file + "-" + tm_dst + ".log")
```

Comment: Thank you Karn Kumar, i'll try it.